# Fill spinner from EditText value

Tags: android, spinner

I managed to create the account and authentication when I click on the register button I redirect to login page after that  I create a new activity (rdv_detail) which contains a spinner which recovers the values ​​entered names. the problem it is when I create a new account I click on register normally I have to redirect to login page but I redirect to the page (rdv_detail) the spinner managed to recover the value entered at the beginning in the edit text field but when I reconnect by the same user the spinner is empty and I want the spinner to keep all the values ​​entered (name) at the start by the form is there anyone who can help me because I don't know exactly where the error is but I don't have the result I want (account.java -> login.java-> click on a button-> rdv_detail.java (which contains the spinner)

account.java

```
public class account extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText nameDoctor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);



    registerButton = findViewById(R.id.btt_register);

    nameDoctor = findViewById(R.id.name_doc);


}


//code

private void registerDoctor() {
    String name = nameDoctor.getText().toString();

   //code



    final Doctor doctor = new Doctor(name, city, adress, email, tel, speciality, code);
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(doctor.email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new 
    OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (!task.isComplete()) {
                Toast.makeText(account.this, "Error ...: " + 
    task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("doctor", "Error....: " + 
    task.getException().getMessage());
            } else {

                Log.e("Adddoctor", "user account created");


                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        SaveDoctorData(doctor);

                        Intent sendNameIntent = new Intent(account.this, rdv_detail.class);
                        String name=nameDoctor.getText().toString();
                        sendNameIntent.putExtra("nameDoctor",name);
                        startActivity(sendNameIntent);



                    }
                }).start();
            }
        }
    });
}

    private void SaveDoctorData(Doctor doctor){
    db.collection("doctor").add(doctor).addOnCompleteListener(new 
    OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                        if (!task.isComplete()) {
                            Toast.makeText(Compte.this, "Error  ...: " + 
   task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e("doctor", "Error: " + 
   task.getException().getMessage());
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(account.this, " user account created", 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            redirectToLoginPage();


                        }
                    }
                });
}

   private void redirectToLoginPage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, login.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

    public void cancel(View view) {
    redirectToLoginPage();
}


}
```

rdv_detail.java

```
 //code
 public class rdv_detail extends AppCompatActivity implements 
 DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener,View.OnClickListener{
   //code
   Spinner spinner_doc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rdv_detail);

    spinner_doc =findViewById(R.id.spinner_doctor);



   String nameExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra("nameDoctor");
    if(nameExtra !=null)
    {

        ArrayList<String> spinnerData = new ArrayList<String>();
        spinnerData.add(nameExtra);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rdv_detail.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerData);

        spinner_doc.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }




}
```

}